# Facebook C# SDK Authorization Problem

Tags: c#, facebook, facebook-c#-sdk

I have an iFrame Facebook application.  I am using the Facebook C# SDK, `Facebook` and `Facebook.Web` libraries.

When a user first comes to my application I create a `FacebookApp` object on `page_load()`.  If the `app.Session` is null I create a `CavasAuthorizer(app)` then call `Authorize()`.

Two problems:

First, the redirect URL that is generated by calling `Authorize` causes Facebook to error with a bad "next" parameter.  Says the "next" parameter is not owned by the application. It looks like this:

```
next=http://localhost:4002/facebookredirect.axd/mygame_dev/mygame.aspx
```

I can edit the code in `CanvasURLBuilder` to make the next look like this:

```
next=http://localhost:4002/mygame.aspx
```

At this point the URL works if I cut and paste into a browser however it brings me to my second issue.

When the code runs the user is presented with a mostly empty page with a mid-sized Facebook image and a link "go to Facebook".  When the user clicks on the link it then takes the user to the correct authorization page for my application.

I have a feeling these are two possibly related issues but potentially separate.

Any help here would be greatly appreciated.

-Andy

Comment: What is your Callback url set to in the web.config?

Comment: I don't see a "callbackUrl" in my web config.  I have a "canvasSettings" tag with a "canvasPageUrl" property.  If that is what you mean it is set to "http://apps.facebook.com/mygame_dev/", it's the same as I have set in the Facebook setup page.

Answer (score 2):

For the first problem

Make sure the site Url in the app configuration page is set to http://apps.facebook.com/**[your_app]**/

[image]

For the second problem.

When you are not authorized you are redirected to the login url but you can't do it from your iframe since it will redirect the iframe and you will get a Facebook inside facebook.
You should use `window.top.location = ...` to redirect the parent window.

**EDIT**

Facebook C# SDK Already does this for you when using the Mvc part of the SDK. Since you are using webforms you should use this code that is the equivalent.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var fb = new FacebookApp();
    var auth = new CanvasAuthorizer(fb);

    if (!auth.IsAuthorized())
    {
        var url = auth.GetLoginUrl(new HttpRequestWrapper(Request));

        var content = CanvasUrlBuilder.GetCanvasRedirectHtml(url);
        Response.ContentType = "text/html";
        Response.Write(content);
        Response.End();
        return;
    }

    //...Go on if authorized
}
```

Comment: Ok, so I tried the above code and used it on my outward facing server.  I have my Facebook configuration set properly, the only oddity is that my web server is listening on a non-default port, 4000.

Comment: When I run the code above, Facebook gives an error, the callback URI is not owned by the application.  The URI looks like http://www.mysite.com:4000/facebookredirect.axd/mygame_dev/mygame.aspx.  If I hack the CanvasUrlBuilder to make the UIR look like http://www.mysite.com:4000/mygame.aspx the redirect works!  However when I authorize it then sends me to the game but outside the iFrame...  /sigh  You think the non-default port is causing me trouble?

Comment: Ok so I just answered my own question.  The port redirect is the problem.  I set my website to use the default port then removed the redirect from the Facebook setting and it worked.  HOWEVER, after I authorize the application Facebook return redirection loads my game outside of the normal Facebook iFrame and it looks understandably bad....

Comment: You should redirect to the url that looks like http://mysite.com:4000/facebookredirect.axd/mygame_dev/mygame.aspx . That works because in the web.config you have to set the handler like this in IIS 6 `<system.web><httpHandlers><add verb="*" path="facebookredirect.axd" type="Facebook.Web.FacebookAppRedirectHttpHandler, Facebook.Web" /></httpHandlers></system.web>` or like this in IIS 7 `<system.webServer><handlers><add name="facebookredirect.axd" verb="*" path="facebookredirect.axd" type="Facebook.Web.FacebookAppRedirectHttpHandler, Facebook.Web" /></handlers></system.webServer>`

Comment: Unfortunately that does not seem to work.  My web.config is set up properly for the .axd handler but it never even gets that far.  When the authorization redirects to facebook for authorization, Facebook throws an API Error Code: 191 "The specified URL is not owned by the application", "Redirect_uri is not owned by the application".

Comment: /sigh..  I had set the site URL in my Facebook control panel but NOT the Site Domain...  I'm an idiot.  Sorry for wasting your time Carlos and thanks for the help!

Comment: @Andrew. I forgot myself the very same thing, the other day that's why i have that image to remind myself. BTW I don't remeber reading that you're supposed to do this in the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

To test locally make sure your Site URL and Canvas URL in facebook is something like http://localhost:8181/yourpage.  Then make sure in VS you set the setting under project properties\Web so that ports are not dynamically generated and you can use 8181 (or whatever port you like, as long as it is the same as in FB).

Answer (score -1):

I think your Callback url in your web config is pointing to localhost.  You can't do that since the code actually runs inside of Facebooks IFrame.  Localhost is localhost to the facebook web server.  You will have to give a valid url in the Callback key in your web.config.  If you don't have a domain you can map to your ip then check out any of the free dynamic dns clients out there.  No-ip is one exammple (and one I use personally).

Comment: localhost is localhost for your browser not to facebook.

Comment: Technically localhost for the server, not the browser.